# Easiest way to get GTK+ to run in Windows with IDE

Tags: ide, gtk

I've been trying to get GTK+ to compile using Dev-C++ or Code::Blocks IDE, but I cannot get either to work.

I wondered if there's someone that knows an IDE where GTK+ is installed as part of the IDE, and it just works?

Its got to be running under windows.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already looked at

http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html ?

Is that what you are having problems with?

---

Also see the windows version of [monodevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Download/MonoDevelop_2.2_Released)

Comment: Yes I've looked at that, but I cannot seem to get it to work.  In MonoDev can you code in C using GTK+?

Comment: No, Monodevelop is for .NET-oid languages .. but afaik it comes with a opensource windows binding to GTK ..